# Localization in MVC 5 - How can I render multi-lingual text in my view using a resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a multi-lingual navigation in an MVC 5 application.

What I've done:

1. Set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to either "en-US" or "es-ES" based on cookie value (defaults to English
   unless user selects Spanish)
2. Created three resource files (this is my first time using them, so I'm not certain I fully understand the concept...) Index.resx, Resouce.en-US.resx, Resouce.es-ES.resx. Each resource file is in a folder called App_GlobalResources folder
3. Added a name/value combination to each .resx file, Home/Home for Index.resx and en-US.resx, and Home/Casa for es-ES.resx
4. Tried using `@Resources.Index.Home` in my layout file, thinking that when the value of `CurrentUICulture` changed from en-US to es-ES and visa-versa, the language would change based on the values in my resource files.

Could someone please let me know how I can get the Spanish text when the value `CurrentUICulture`is "es-ES", and the English text when it is "en-US"?

[_Layout.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2Ul.png)

[Resource.resx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQAG.png)

**EDIT**

I should have stated - `@Resources.Index.Home` does render the text "Home" in the navigation. However, when I switch `CurrentUICulture` to "es-ES", it still renders "Home", not "Casa"

**EDIT 2**

Here is how I set `CurrentUICulture` is global.asax

```
   public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["lang"] == null)
            {
                HttpCookie lang = new HttpCookie("lang");
                lang.Value = "english";
                lang.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30d);
                Response.Cookies.Add(lang);
            }
            else if (Request.Cookies["lang"] != null)
            {
                if (Request.Cookies["lang"].Value != null && Request.Cookies["lang"].Value == "english")
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
                }
                else if (Request.Cookies["lang"].Value != null && Request.Cookies["lang"].Value == "spanish")
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-es");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It should work, do you have any error message ? Can you post how your controller which initialize your CurrentUICulture ? What do you have in @Resources.Index.Home ? Does it show anything ?

Comment: Thanks - good point - there is no error. Please see my update. `@Resources.Index.Home` does render the text "Home", however it does not change to "Casa" when `CurrentUICulture` is set to "es-ES"

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize your CurrentUICulture

Comment: @Yanga just posted.

Comment: Did you try to force the culture, just add for exemple                   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-es"); at the end of Application_AuthenticateRequest (after "if", "else if" code)

Comment: If you delete your cookies and change "lang.Value = "english"; with lang.Value = "spanish"; still the same problem ?

Comment: @Yanga I did not, I shouldn't have to because either the cookie exists or does not exist, and either way there will be a value set for `CurrentUICulture`. Just to be sure I am outputting `@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name` in my view to show what the current value is, and it either shows "en-US" or "es-ES" based on my dropdown selection in the header

Comment: Look like in your code that the culture will by only in English, you set your cookie to "english" when it's null and there is no way to set it to "spanish"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to replace `@Resources.Index.Home` with `@Resources.Home`.
This is ur understanding about localization.
Every app with localization (say N cultures) must have N `.resx`-files with the **same** name but different suffixes. + Default culture can be used without suffixes.
So u have 2 cultures - u must use 2 .resx files, not more. So `Index.resx` is not needed at all.
This should work. If not, more fixes:
- Don't use App_GlobalResources folder. Just create `.resx` in common project-folders or in project root folder, just as in desktop .NET-apps.
   This helped me, hope  this will help u.